# How do I make the iPad ignore user-scalable=no on my mobile friendly site?

Tags: ipad, html

I would like to include the `user-scalable=no` option in my web template so that 640px wide devices and below do not scale. The current design scales well at screen sizes larger than 640  but the iPad (with a 1024px wide interface landscape) is obeying the user-scalable option. I want the iPad to behave like a desktop and allow users to zoom. I do not want the iPhone and the Android to zoom.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
```

How do I force the iPad, and other mobile devices with a screen width of 640px or larger, into ignoring the user-scalable=no option? Im looking for the same behavior achieved using css media queries where you can specify a range of screen widths to apply the setting to.

Comment: It is abolutely annoying for a user to prevent scaling. It is arrogant if you think you know what scaling is sufficient for a user. Stop it at all and make your site ready for scaling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually got what I was looking for by using the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand what you are trying to achieve. However, did you look at [other scaling properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html), maybe you can achieve what you want using these. With the following settings the user can zoom, but not below 640px width, which is what I assume you want:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: This set the minimum page width to 640px, so on an iphone with a responsive grid, the content is no longer fitted to the page, but larger.